# How can I put several requests in one transaction in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

My code is like the following:

```
...
var f1 = function(trans) {
  var store = trans.objectStore('ObjectStore');
  store.clear();
};
var f2 = function(trans) {
  var store = trans.objectStore('ObjectStore');
  store.add({id: 1, data: 'text'});
};
...
var trans = DB.connection.transaction(['ObjectStore'], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
trans.onerror = function() { alert('ERROR'); };
trans.oncomplete = function() { alert('DONE'); };
...
```

The problem us that i get the DONE alert right after `clear` and on the second request exception appears.

Is it possible to "reuse" the transaction in IndexedDB?

UPD: I've found that the code above works as I expect in the latest Chromium nightly build.

Answer (score 5):

[According to Jonas Sicking](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2011/11/indexeddb-apis-javascriptnext.html), a Mozilla dev and co-spec writer for IndexedDB, a transaction is committed when the last callback fires. So to keep a transaction alive, you should be able to reuse it via successive callbacks.

You're using `oncomplete` above, but `onsucess` should work equally as well.

You can find the transaction object as an attribute of the request object that's returned on callback.

> The following sentence isn't correct "Transactions today auto-commit
>   when the transaction variable goes out of scope and no more requests
>   can be placed against it".
>
> Transaction never automatically commit when a variable goes out of
>   scope. Generally they only commit when the last success/error callback
>   fires and that callback schedules no more requests. So it's not
>   related to the scope of any variables.
>
> The only exception to this is if you create a transaction but place no
>   requests against it. In that case the transaction is "committed"
>   (whatever that means for a transaction which has no requests) as soon
>   as you return to the event loop. In this scenario you could
>   technically "commit" the transaction as soon as all references to it
>   go out of scope, but it's not a particularly interesting use case to
>   optimize.

Based on a [spec example](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idl-def-IDBRequest) below, you should be able to find the transaction object at `evt.transaction`, and you can do a new transaction and add a new `onsuccess` event listener.

```
 var request = indexedDB.open('AddressBook', 'Address Book');
 request.onsuccess = function(evt) {...};
 request.onerror = function(evt) {...};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please give an example?

Comment: It's hard to post full example code for IDB (needs object store creation and data addition setup code before you can query) but I've added a bit about where you can find the transaction (it's an attribute of the object passed to `onsuccess`). Using that transaction object is like using any other transaction object so whatever code you have for that should work again there.

Comment: For me the transaction is in `evt.target.transaction`.