# Safari - "TransactionInactiveError" using Facebook IndexedDB Polyfill

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, indexeddb, polyfills

We are using the [Facebook IndexedDB Polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill/) to allow the IndexedDB API to be utilised in Safari/ Mobile Safari. However, we are experiencing a "TransactionInactiveError" when attempting to update records - the error originates from line 1567 of the Polyfill.js file: `if (!me._active) throw new util.error("TransactionInactiveError");`

Here's a quick example I've put together. Simply add the Facebook Polyfill script tag reference and run in Safari:

```
var db;
var request = indexedDB.open("polyfillTest");

request.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
    db = request.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore("books", {keyPath: "isbn"});
    var titleIndex = store.createIndex("by_title", "title", {unique: true});
    var authorIndex = store.createIndex("by_author", "author");

    // Populate with initial data.
    store.put({title: "Quarry Memories", author: "Fred", isbn: 123456});
    store.put({title: "Water Buffaloes", author: "Fred", isbn: 234567});
    store.put({title: "Bedrock Nights", author: "Barney", isbn: 345678});

    updateItem(store);
};

request.onsuccess = function () {
    db = request.result;
};

function updateItem(store) {
    var request = store.get(123456);

    request.onsuccess = function () {
        var book = request.result;
        book.title = "New Title";
        book.author = "New Author";

        var updateRequest = store.put(book);
        updateRequest.onsuccess = function (evt) {
            console.log("Book updated successfully.");
        };
        updateRequest.onerror = function (evt) {
            console.error("Book could not be updated.");
        };
    };
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are typically kept active until [the last callback with a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484965/how-can-i-put-several-requests-in-one-transaction-in-indexeddb/10486963#10486963) releases that reference. So this suggests to me your transaction is auto-commiting.

I suspect it may have something to do with your re-use of the `versionchange` transaction for `puts` and `gets`. After many headaches with this issue, in my [library](https://github.com/editor/dash/) I've opted for a model where I [allow all version change transactions to fully commit](https://github.com/editor/dash/blob/master/lib/dash.dev.js#L888) before trying to do CRUD operations on the same store.

I'm not fully able to explain why, but based on many days of frustration, keeping long-lived versionchanges seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: Agree. No reason to use versionchange transaction for db op requests.